# Error when importing h5/h5py on conda: undefined symbol: H5Pget_fapl_direct

Tags: conda, h5py

I installed h5py using:

conda install h5py
pip install h5py

The following packages are already installed in my conda environment:

```
h5                        0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.7.0           nompi_py310h06dffec_100    conda-forge
```

But I receive the error when I try to import h5:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/vol/ideadata/oc69ubiw/Explainer_GNN/patho-quant-explainer/core/generate_cell_graphs.py", line 14, in <module>
  from histocartography.preprocessing import (
File "/vol/ideadata/oc69ubiw/conda/pathoexplainer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/histocartography/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .pipeline import PipelineRunner, BatchPipelineRunner
File "/vol/ideadata/oc69ubiw/conda/pathoexplainer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/histocartography/pipeline.py", line 12, in <module>
 import h5py
File "/vol/ideadata/oc69ubiw/conda/pathoexplainer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
from . import version
File "/vol/ideadata/oc69ubiw/conda/pathoexplainer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h5py/version.py", line 15, in <module>
from . import h5 as _h5
File "h5py/h5.pyx", line 1, in init h5py.h5
ImportError: /vol/ideadata/oc69ubiw/conda/pathoexplainer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h5py/defs.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: H5Pget_fapl_direct
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me:

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install --no-cache-dir h5py
```